# Why is DB2 for IBM i (AS400 DB2) field name started and ended by double quotes as "THISID" when it's imported from MS EXCEL?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

Today, I found some DB2 field name gets started and ended by double quotes when I was using `STRSQL` and F4. But it seems that it happens randomly.
Is there anyone can answer for me why it's happened? 
Also I'd like to hear if we can keep this as it is or is needed to be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 has 2 types of names:

An ordinary identifier is an uppercase letter followed by zero or more characters, each of which is an uppercase letter, a digit, or the underscore character. Note that ordinary identifiers are converted to uppercase. An ordinary identifier should not be a reserved word.

A delimited identifier is a sequence of one or more characters enclosed within SQL escape characters. The sequence must consist of one or more characters. Leading blanks in the sequence are significant. Trailing blanks in the sequence are not significant. The length of a delimited identifier does not include the two SQL escape characters. Note that delimited identifiers are not converted to uppercase. The escape character is the quotation mark (").

Ref: [DB2 for i SQL Identifiers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzsqlidts.htm)

Comment: Thanks Buck, I checked the all of this particular Field name with Double quotes, then found out there are two kinds of this Field. One has varchar and length 6 and the other one has char and length 8... So is that a reason why that AS400 tries to add Double quotes to identify?

Comment: I don't think so; at least I've never seen the data type influence whether a column name is delimited or not.  Go to a green screen and DSPFD on the table to see if the column name is actually delimited in DB2.

Comment: It looks like Delimited in the DSPFD / DSPFFD. 

  THISID     CHAR            6       8        44        Both     THISID
  Variable length field -- Allocated length :  None                  
  Coded Character Set Identifier  . . . . . :  65535

Total number of fields . . . . . . . . . . . :           5

Comment: I think you're confirming that one of them is delimited and one of them is ordinary.  If so, that's how the database designer created the table.  Just remember which one is delimited and use the double quotes with that one and that's all you need to do.

Comment: If the column shows an 'Alternative name' when listed with DSPFFD, and quotes are part of it, then either the listed 'Field' name or the 'Alternative name' can be used by SQL. The quote characters are part of the 'Alternative name', so they need to be there when that name is referenced.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating the table from Excel, I assume by using the Transfer Data add-in?

Two reason why a column name gets quoted...

1) It's a reserved word.  For example, DATE as a column name
`CREATE TABLE MYTBL("DATE" DATE NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT)`
2) to preserve case
`CREATE TABLE MYTBL("MyColumn" CHAR(10) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT)`

In the first case, the system is often smart enough to allow you to reference the column without quoting it; this works:
`select date from mytbl`

However, in the second case, you always have to reference the column with quotes and the correct case; this **DOES NOT** work:
`select mycolumn from mytbl`

Comment: Thanks Charles. I believe she uses System i Data transfer. Yes, I aware of that I'm not able to treat the Field name with Double quotes as the regular Field name without Double quotes. Perhaps, is there any other issues for this to be used?